# Export online Office 365 Excel workbook to tsv/csv via url

Tags: http, office365

I have a script that downloads a Google Sheet's workbook as a TSV file but my employeer want's to migrate to Office 365.

It makes a request to a url like:
`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXX/export?gid='XXX'&format=tsv'`

I looked through Microsofts online documentation and couldn't find anything similar. I am wondering what the best way to replicate this inside Office 365 would be?